# Trigger action attribute of form from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have validated all my form fields and after that, I would like to trigger form action from submit function. I have tried many ways but nothing seems to work. Any help appreciated.

```
(function() {
    //FORM VALIDATOR
    formValidator = {
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDom: function() {
            //MAIN PARENT ELEMENT
            this.contactForm = document.getElementById("contactForm");
            //MAIN FORM ELEMENTS
            this.formBody = document.getElementById("formBody");
            this.inputContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("inputContainer");
            //USER INPUT ELEMENTS
            //INPUT FIELDS
            this.fields = {
                company: document.getElementById("company"),
                industry: document.getElementById("industry"),
                //rest of the fields

            };
            this.submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
        }
        submitForm: function() {
                //I want to trigger form action from this part but nothing seems to work
                document.getElementById("myForm").action = "https://google.com";

            }
        };
        //INITIATE FORM VALIDATOR
        formValidator.init();
}());
```

//HTML

```
    <div id="formBody" class="formBody">
        <form action="https://google.com" method="POST" name="becomessaform" id="becomessaform">
            <input type=hidden name="oid" value="****">
            <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="">
            <div class="row form-fields ">
                {/* all fields go here */}
            </div>
            <div class="row form-fields submit-button-cf"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button-submit"/></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form in JS by using [submit()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp).

In your code, that would be:

```
submitForm: function() {
    document.getElementById("becomessaform").submit();
};
```

Comment: What part is not working? How do you call the function? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I changed the name attribute of button, submit function was creating the issue. Fixed it. Thank you.